# Is it necessary to call SPWeb.Update() after setting AllowUnsafeUpdates?

Tags: wss-3.0, spweb

Amidst working on [resolving this issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12424/cannot-upload-to-a-permissions-enabled-document-library-even-with-runwithelevated), there's something I was curious about, and something that I've been very inconsistent about in my code.

If you enable `SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true`, do you have to call `SPWeb.Update()` for that to be in effect? Or is just the one statement sufficient? I re-examined the WSS 3.0 SDK to look it up again, but either it's buried in a really random article or they aren't explaining it well.

I imagine that whatever is the case for setting it to true, it'll be the same for setting it to false in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to call `SPWeb.Update()` because the `AllowUnsafeUpdates` property is not persisted. (Reference [Best Pattern for AllowUnsafeUpdates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213882/best-pattern-for-allowunsafeupdates))

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I should go fix all those erroneous Updates, then. Unfortunately, though, this still didn't fix my non-permitted uploads...